# PHP - Getting URL from localhost and online

Tags: php, wamp

OK, so localhost, I use `WAMP` and its `http://localhost/PROJECTNAME/` and online it's `http://PROJECTNAME.COM/`

So, by using

`<?php echo "Load config file from: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>`

I get this running on `localhost/quiz`: `Load config file from: http://localhost` while running it online I get it correct.

How would I get this URL to work both locally and online?

Comment: Since I'm loading it from `localhost/quiz` ... then `http://localhost/quiz/`? But it would be different for other projects... if I loaded it from like `localhost/test`it'd be `http://localhost/test2/`

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` is just the part between `//` and `/`. That should be true for localhost and for the domain server.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

On localhost, it should return something like `http://localhost/quiz` and on a website, it will be `http://example.com/quiz`.

Answer (score 6):

Use relative paths. That way, you'll be independent of which domain you are running this on. And since it seems like you are loading a config file, I doubt you'd need to provide absolute URL anywhere outside the application. So relative path should be good enough.

`<?php require('/path/to/config/file.php);
?>`

Edit:

Based on your comments, you may do this:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://'.($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']==='localhost')?'localhost/PROJECTNAME':$_SERV‌​ER['SERVER_NAME']; 
echo $url; 
?>
```

Comment: I won't need to change this if I put this online?

Comment: But I want to use this to link to hyperlinks... not just files.

Comment: You can use this: <?php $url = 'http://'.($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']==='localhost')?'localhost/PROJECTNAME':$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; echo $url; ?>